# Automate installing agents on VMware platform

Tags: scripting, automation, chef-infra, salt

In a vmware vsphere platform with over 200 virtual machines with Centos and Windows machines, would it be possible to install chef client and salt agents on all these machines using vCenter API or Powercli or any other scripts, is that possible ? can some one share any thoughts and ideas as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: That's a really broad question... How do you handle installing updates/software on thoses machines actually ?

Comment: Once the chef or salt agents are installed, its just we trigger from the chef server or salt master server to push the updates from the custom repo. for linux machines its usually with yum, have a custom yum repository, like wise its the same for windows, have a custom wsus server.

Current challenge is to install chef or salt agents to all those server.